# How to get data from a firebase table by using another table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying get my orders listed as users first and then later when clicked taken to the place where all items can be seen. I have set the order ID as the user uid and now I'm trying to get the uid and from that fetch user data. The mykey i have defined as public in starting but I think I'm using it inside loop and hence can't access it outside. Please help

[image]

Code I'm trying

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order");
    firebaseDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    firebaseDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    firebaseDatabase.keepSynced(true);



    firebaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                mykey = snapshot.getKey();


            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();





    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>().setQuery(firebaseDatabase2.child(mykey), Users.class).build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, Orders.UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, Orders.UsersViewHolder>(options)
    {

        @Override
        public Orders.UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_layout,parent,false);

            return new Orders.UsersViewHolder(view);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(Orders.UsersViewHolder holder, int position, Users model) {

            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getMobile());






        }

    };

    mylist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();


}

public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mview;


    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mview = itemView;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {

        TextView userNameView = mview.findViewById(R.id.username);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }


    public void setStatus(String status) {

        TextView userStatusView = mview.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        userStatusView.setText(status);

    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The mykey i've got it shows null point exception i tried it as a toast it shows when toast is set inside the loop but when same is set outside the loop the string mykey is null

Comment: If you add `Log.d("TAG", mykey);` right after `mykey = snapshot.getKey();`, is there something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: your code is incomplete. But with this code you should get the last key of Order node in mykey.  please try Alex Mamo way. it will confirm that at least data is coming or not.

Comment: Yes the keys are coming